# Function counting median (python)

Tags: python, median

```
def median(lista):
    if len(lista) % 2 == 1:
        float(x) = (len(lista))/(2)
        lista2 = sorted(lista)
        y = x + 0.5
        return lista2[y]
    else:
        x = len(lista)
        total = 0
        for i in lista:
            total += i
        return total/x
```

What's wrong with this function? It's showing error

> File "python", line 3
>   SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

I know you can tell me how to write this function in 1 million different ways, but could you explain why this exact version doesn't work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? `float(x) = (len(lista))/(2)`?

Comment: Line 3: you have `float(x) = (len(lista))/(2)`. You're calling the function `float()` on `x`, but you can't assign a value to that.

Answer (score 0):

The `float` conversion is being applied on the wrong side of the assignment `float(x) = (len(lista))/(2)`. Move it to the other like `x = float((len(lista))/(2))` and the code works

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you're trying to get half the length as a float value; is that right?

If so, you have to apply the `float` conversion where you functionally need it, rather than as if it were a linguistic modifier:

```
x = float(len(lista))/(2)
```

Or simply coerce that result with a float constant:

```
x = len(lista) / 2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong with your function:

```
def median(lista):
    if len(lista) % 2 == 1:
        float(x) = (len(lista))/(2)  # you assign to a function?
        lista2 = sorted(lista)
        y = x + 0.5                  # y is now a float
        return lista2[y]             # accessing the float index?
    else:                            # here you calculate the average
        x = len(lista)
        total = 0
        for i in lista:
            total += i
        return total/x
```

The median of an even list is **not the average**. It is the average of the **two elements in the middle**.

You can simply write the following function:

```
def median(lista):
    listb = sorted(lista)
    n_lista = len(lista)
    half = n_lista//2
    if n_lista % 2:
        return lista[half]
    else:
        return 0.5*(lista[half-1]+lista[half])
```